# Phpunit coverage-text is not displaying all classes files tested

Tags: php, unit-testing

I'm running phpunit in my project but the coverage-text is not displaying all the classes inside the folder in whitelist.

I've tried with PHPUnit 7.5.12 and PHPUnit 8.2.1.

I've tried with PHP 7.2 and 7.3 (I'm using 7.3 right now)

Xdebug version is v2.7.2

My phpunit.xml:

```
<phpunit backupGlobals="false"
         backupStaticAttributes="false"
         colors="true"
         convertErrorsToExceptions="true"
         convertNoticesToExceptions="true"
         convertWarningsToExceptions="true"
         processIsolation="false"
         stopOnFailure="false">
    <testsuites>
        <testsuite name="Api Connector">
            <directory suffix="Test.php">tests</directory>
        </testsuite>
    </testsuites>
    <filter>
        <whitelist addUncoveredFilesFromWhitelist="true">
            <directory suffix=".php">src</directory>
        </whitelist>
    </filter>
</phpunit>
```

[phpunit coverage-text result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OwTbr.png)

[And here's the list of files in my project](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4gkPN.png)

As you can see not all the files in my project are displayed in the coverage result and I don't know why.

In fact all files in the tests directory are tested because some of the 114 functions tested are functions in files not displayed in the coverage result.

EDIT: All files in Entity folder extends ApiRest.php which is an abstract class. The files not displayed in the coverage summary are those that haven't custom functions. If I override a function for example in ApiCompany.php, ApiCompany is displayed in the coverage summary.